# Save and Share images universal-image-loader

Tags: android

I'm using universal image loader to display several images from urls , in ImagePager Activity I'd like to add Save and Share buttons , but where ever I try to write their codes I got multiple erros ? Can Anyone knows where exactly I can use these functions and what is the best codes for them ?

***ImagePagerActivity.java***

```
package com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader;
import static com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.Constants.IMAGES;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ImagePagerActivity extends BaseActivity {

DisplayImageOptions options;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_pager);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
    int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
        .resetViewBeforeLoading()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
        .build();

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls));
    pager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);



}




private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private String[] images;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    ImagePagerAdapter(String[] images) {
        this.images = images;
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        View rootView = (View) object;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();

        if (drawable != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
            if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }

        }

        ((ViewPager) container).removeView(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View container) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View view, int position) {
        final View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, null);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);

        imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted() {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason) {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_error);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View container) {
    }

}
}
```

Comment: check this out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855166/download-image-stream-from-android-universal-image-loader

Answer (score 2):

```
Bitmap mSaveBit = imageLoader.getMemoryCache().get(Constants.IMAGESURLS[pager.getCurrentItem()]);
                    File imageFile = null;
                    if(null==mSaveBit){
                        imageFile =  imageLoader.getDiscCache().get(Constants.IMAGESURLS[pager.getCurrentItem()]);
                     }
```

You can try this. I successfully obtained.

Comment: please add the English translation to your text.

Comment: DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(false)
                .cacheOnDisk(false);
It will not work in this case.