# Save Images to external public storage using Universal Image Downloader?

Tags: android, exception, try-catch, universal-image-loader, fileoutputstream

I'm attempting to save images to the external SD card using Universal Image Loader. I was following this extremely outdated code fragment from the author, nostra, here:

[Download Image stream from android universal image loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855166/download-image-stream-from-android-universal-image-loader/13894889#13894889)

I'm interested in recreating this successfully, but when I tried, I got

this error:

```
    06-21 07:56:22.586  17647-17647/as;dlkfa E/libEGL﹕ call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-21 07:56:27.562  17647-17647/;alsdjf E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
06-21 07:56:30.965  17647-17647/;aldjf; E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
06-21 07:56:32.737  17647-17647/a;sdjfl E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.utils.IoUtils.copyStream(IoUtils.java:73)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.utils.IoUtils.copyStream(IoUtils.java:50)
            at ;a;ldsfkj.MediaDisplayActivity.saveToGallery(MediaDisplayActivity.java:344)
            at as;dlkfj.MediaDisplayActivity.onMenuItemClick(MediaDisplayActivity.java:298)
            at android.widget.PopupMenu.onMenuItemSelected(PopupMenu.java:142)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:175)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1507)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3336)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've changed his original code to be this. It is being called on a menu item click:

```
    private void saveToGallery()
{
    String imageUrl = imageUrls.get(pager.getCurrentItem());

    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File fileForImage = new File(path, imageUrl);

    InputStream sourceStream = null;
    File cachedImage = ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache().get(imageUrl);
    if (cachedImage.exists()) { // if image was cached by UIL
        try {
            sourceStream = new FileInputStream(cachedImage);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else { // otherwise - download image
        ImageDownloader downloader = new BaseImageDownloader(this);
        try {
            sourceStream = downloader.getStream(imageUrl, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // TODO : use try-finally to close streams
    OutputStream targetStream = null;
    try {
        targetStream = new FileOutputStream(fileForImage);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        IoUtils.copyStream(sourceStream, targetStream, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        targetStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        sourceStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Line 344 is:

```
IoUtils.copyStream(sourceStream, targetStream, null);
```

Read comments for fix. Basically, I was using bad characters like https**:**

Also, here's my new code, it works, but It still won't create a album for your app which is pretty desirable if you want users to navigate quickly through their own albums. I'll keep begging for help from the coding gods in the comments. Also, it doesn't handle when saving the same image yet.

```
    //TODO upon uninstall ensure the files are still there
    //TODO make sure this janky stuff don't crash if you save the same stuff twice
    private boolean saveToGallery() {
        String imageUrl = imageUrls.get(pager.getCurrentItem());

        int i = imageUrl.length()-1;
        while(imageUrl.charAt(i) != '/')
        {
            i--;
        }
        String newImageUrl = imageUrl.substring(i+1);
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File fileForImage = new File(path, newImageUrl);
//        if (!fileForImage.mkdirs()) {
//            Log.e("shit", "Directory not created");
//        }

        boolean saved = false;

        InputStream sourceStream = null;
        File cachedImage = ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache().get(imageUrl);
        try {
            if (cachedImage != null && cachedImage.exists()) { // if image was cached by UIL
                sourceStream = new FileInputStream(cachedImage);
            } else { // otherwise - download image
                ImageDownloader downloader = new BaseImageDownloader(this);
                sourceStream = downloader.getStream(imageUrl, null);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            L.e(e);
        }

        if (sourceStream != null) {
            try {
                System.out.println(fileForImage.getAbsolutePath());
                OutputStream targetStream = new FileOutputStream(fileForImage);
                IoUtils.copyStream(sourceStream, targetStream, null);
                targetStream.close();
                sourceStream.close();
                saved = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                L.e(e);
            }
        }

        //Updates the gallery, dunno how though lol, yay SO
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        return saved;

    }
```

Alright everyone, all I had to do was move the mkdirs() call before the appending of the url file. I'm too tired right now to figure out the ordering of things, but it is surely due to that. Here's the new code. This will save an image to an album in your app if you are using universal image loader and part of the URL for the file name, otherwise, no soup for you:

```
//TODO upon uninstall ensure the files are still there
//TODO make sure this janky stuff don't crash if you save the same stuff twice
private boolean saveToGallery() {
    String imageUrl = imageUrls.get(pager.getCurrentItem());

    int i = imageUrl.length()-1;
    while(imageUrl.charAt(i) != '/')
    {
        i--;
    }
    String newImageUrl = imageUrl.substring(i+1);
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/Your app name here");

    if (!path.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e("shit", "Directory not created");
    }
    File fileForImage = new File(path, newImageUrl);


    boolean saved = false;

    InputStream sourceStream = null;
    File cachedImage = ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache().get(imageUrl);
    try {
        if (cachedImage != null && cachedImage.exists()) { // if image was cached by UIL
            sourceStream = new FileInputStream(cachedImage);
        } else { // otherwise - download image
            ImageDownloader downloader = new BaseImageDownloader(this);
            sourceStream = downloader.getStream(imageUrl, null);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        L.e(e);
    }

    if (sourceStream != null) {
        try {
            System.out.println(fileForImage.getAbsolutePath());
            OutputStream targetStream = new FileOutputStream(fileForImage);
            IoUtils.copyStream(sourceStream, targetStream, null);
            targetStream.close();
            sourceStream.close();
            saved = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            L.e(e);
        }
    }

    //Updates the gallery, dunno how though lol, yay SO
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
    return saved;

}
```

Comment: Line 344 in saveToGallery causes for a NullPointerException on one of the streams as you can read in your logcat. What is on line 344?

Comment: IoUtils.copyStream(sourceStream, targetStream, null);

Comment: Ok. Now one of the streams is null as i already remarked. Did you find out which one? Your code is buggy. The try block where targetStream is instantiated has a catch block in case things go wrong. If there is a catch you should return there as it makes no sence to continu with a null pointer in that case.

Comment: Based on this quick debug:

System.out.println(sourceStream);
System.out.println(targetStream);
IoUtils.copyStream(sourceStream, targetStream, null);

I got:

06-21 09:19:51.394  20427-20427/a;sldkf I/System.out﹕ java.io.FileInputStream@42a30758
06-21 09:19:51.394  20427-20427/a;dslkf I/System.out﹕ null

So targetStream is the culprit! I still have no idea what to do even though we know who the murderer is

Comment: It is strange that the e.printStackTrace() from that catch block does not show up in the logcat. Anyhow the `targetStream=....` is the culprit. And so `fileForImage` is null or indicates to a wrong path or you have no write to external permission in your manifest. Find out the exact full path please. What is fileForImage.getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: I did the System.out.Println() with absolute path, and it gave me:

/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/http:/www.slowyourhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/who-you-want-to-be-via-pinterest.jpg

Also, based off of Nostra's help below, it seems that the logger is now telling me:

open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I have no idea why though, because I took the code used to get a directory off of the google androiddev website

Comment: Well that is a pretty unusual path. That can not be your intention to save it there. First it is not a valid path because of the ":" in it. You have attached the full url starting with http on the storage directory where you most probably only would attach the filename witch ends on .jpg. Indeed you did by using `imageUrl`. Please extract the file name first.

Comment: Alright greenapps, you helped my peasant mind enough, post a hello message in the comments and I'll vote it the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User#### it was a pleasure to help you. If all OP's were that talkative and informing!

Answer (score 2):

I refactored your method, it returns `false` if saving to gallery failed:

```
private boolean saveToGallery() {
    String imageUrl = imageUrls.get(pager.getCurrentItem());
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File fileForImage = new File(path, imageUrl);

    boolean saved = false;

    InputStream sourceStream = null;
    File cachedImage = ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache().get(imageUrl);
    try {
        if (cachedImage != null && cachedImage.exists()) { // if image was cached by UIL
            sourceStream = new FileInputStream(cachedImage);
        } else { // otherwise - download image
            ImageDownloader downloader = new BaseImageDownloader(this);
            sourceStream = downloader.getStream(imageUrl, null);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        L.e(e);
    }

    if (sourceStream != null) {
        try {
            OutputStream targetStream = new FileOutputStream(fileForImage);
            try {   
                IoUtils.copyStream(sourceStream, targetStream, null);
                saved = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                L.e(e);
            } finally {
                targetStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            L.e(e);
        } finally {
            sourceStream.close();
        }
    }

    return saved;
}
```

Comment: If the `targetStream` can not be opened (as is the case here) the just opened `sourceStream` will not be closed.

Comment: NOSTRA, you are a living legend amongst men. Your library has reduced my workload by roughly 90% for my app, and it's highly likely that you saved its life due to that fact. I will certainly credit you once it is complete. For now, I must give the answer to greenapps for walking me along in the comments, if he posts ofc.